# Brunch + Heroku build `Cannot GET /`

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, express, brunch

I've manged to get my Brunch build up on Heroku. **However**, my Express up shows `Cannot GET /` when navigating to the site.

From the log when pushing:

```
       > preso@1.0.0 postinstall /tmp/build_13daabc0-9174-41fd-a59e-c2a894c07256
       > ./node_modules/brunch/bin/brunch build --production

       18 Jun 08:59:09 - info: compiled 21 files into 3 files, copied 23 in 5200ms
-----> Caching node_modules directory for future builds
-----> Cleaning up node-gyp and npm artifacts
-----> Building runtime environment
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web

-----> Compressing... done, 11.8MB
-----> Launching... done, v7
       http://nameless-fortress-7923.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku

To git@heroku.com:nameless-fortress-7923.git
 + 75f1076...9d2a80b master -> master (forced update)
```

package.json dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.4.3",
    "passport-http": "^0.2.2",
    "passport": "^0.2.0",
    "brunch": "^1.7.14",
    "javascript-brunch": "^1.7.1",
    "coffee-script-brunch": "^1.7.3",
    "css-brunch": "^1.7.0",
    "stylus-brunch": "^1.7.0",
    "static-jade-brunch": "^1.7.0",
    "jade-brunch": "^1.5.1",
    "uglify-js-brunch": "^1.7.7",
    "clean-css-brunch": "^1.7.1"
  },
```

My Express simply serves up `public/` (behind some authentication), looking like [this](https://github.com/KATT/boilerplate-heroku-static-nodejs-express-basic-auth/blob/master/server.js).

It gets build successfully but it seems like the `public/` folder gets removed/cleared by Heroku?

Any ideas on why this happens would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a neat solution, but my workaround was simply compiling it locally and adding it to git.

I did a `deploy` command in my `Makefile`, which looks like this

```
default: run

run:
    rm -rf public
    ./node_modules/brunch/bin/brunch w -s

deploy:
    rm -rf public/
    rm -rf build/
    ./node_modules/brunch/bin/brunch build --production
    mv public/ build/
    git add --all build/
    git commit -m "heroku deploy"
    git push heroku master --force
    git reset HEAD~1
    rm -rf build/
    heroku open
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Brunch but with other build tools it creates a dist folder during build. If that dist folder is included in your gitignore it is not being pushed to Heroku.

The same thing may be happening with your public folder.

Comment: I have a `postinstall` script in my `package.json`: `"scripts": { "postinstall": "./node_modules/brunch/bin/brunch build --production"
}`